# How can I get Python stacktraces to show up properly in Google Cloud Trace?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, fastapi, stack-trace, open-telemetry

I have a web service written in python, running on GKE. I've enabled opentelemetry instrumentation via FastAPI contrib package, OTel SDK and cloud trace exporter.

I am able to send and view successful traces, but the exception information seems wrong. I am getting the correct message and `exception.type`, and I'm able to correlate it with my logs, but the stack trace displayed in the cloud console seems completely bogus:

`exception.stacktrace` key in "Logs & Events" tab:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/opentelemetry/trace/__init__.py", line 573, in use_span
    yield span
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/opentelemetry/sdk/trace/__init__.py", line 1045, in st
```

It seems as if it was cut off at `st`, and while seemingly describing the same exception, it doesn't have my, correct stacktrace, which starts with:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/uvicorn/protocols/http/httptools_impl.py", line 426, in run_asgi     result = await app(  # type: ignore[func-returns-value]
```

This exception is attached to every span in this trace up to the root one:

[image: google cloud trace span view showing an event dot on every span]

Is this misconfigured instrumentation? How can I see actual stacktraces in the console?